# Getting Euler rotations for an object and exporting them

Tags: python, add-on

Currently I have add-on that gets rotations from an object, converts angles into a matrix and saves it in a particular format into a text file.

This is what code for that looks like:

```
rot = tuple(chain(*obj.matrix_world.to_3x3().normalized().transposed()))

dump += ['"rotation" "{}"'.format(" ".join(str(r) for r in rot)),]

self.write(self.filepath, "\n".join(dump))
```

I also need to have Euler angles written after "rotation" in the following format:

"angles" "Y Z X"

Where Y, Z and X are angles in degrees.

How would I do that, following analogy with rotation matrix ? Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Should be as simple as:

```
from math import degrees

"{:f} {:f} {:f}".format(*map(degrees, obj.matrix_world.to_euler()))
# '-90.224203 -10.379210 -11.433244'
```

`to_euler()` converts a matrix to an Euler object, with order `XYZ` (regardless of what is set for `rotation_mode`). The angles are given in radians, but they can be simply converted to degrees using `math.degrees()`.

Comment: Thanks! I got this code writing angles now: '"angles" "{:f} {:f} {:f}"'.format(*map(degrees, obj.matrix_world.to_euler())), however, the order is wrong.                                                                                           How do I re-arrange X Y Z to be Y Z X ?

Comment: `e = tuple(map(degrees, obj.matrix_world.to_euler()))` and then `"{:f} {:f} {:f}".format(e[1], e[2], e[0])`

Answer (score 3):

So this is what worked for me (for test cases I tried anyway; with help from some folks on IRC):

```
rot_angles = obj.matrix_world.to_euler()
rot_angles_X = math.degrees(rot_angles[0])
rot_angles_Y = math.degrees(rot_angles[1])
rot_angles_Z = math.degrees(rot_angles[2])

'"angles" "{}"'.format(" ".join( [ str(rot_angles_Y), str(rot_angles_Z), str(rot_angles_X) ] ))
```

Thanks!